# Splitting header and implementation causes significant slow-down

Tags: c++, performance, header-files

When I split the header and implementation in c++, I found that significant slow-down occurs in some situation compared to the header-only one. The minumum working example is like below. In the case below, `get_sum` function is implemented in the header file and `get_sum2`, which is exactly the same implementation as `get_sum`, is implemented in `impl.cpp`. The result shows that time duration to execute is 0.001 [msec] for `get_sum` and 1066.84 [msec] for `get_sum2` (see `main.cpp`), though both have the same implementation. Could anyone explain why this happens?

The following codes can be found [here](https://github.com/HiroIshida/snippets/tree/master/cpp/perf_impl_split).

The header file `header.h`

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class Tester
{
  public:
    Tester(int n){ 
      table_.resize(n);
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        table_[i].resize(n);
      }
    }

    bool get_sum(){
      double s = 0;
      for(auto& subtable : table_){
        for(double e : subtable){
          s += e;
        }
      }
      return s;
    }
    bool get_sum2(); // definition is in impl.cpp
  private:
    vector<vector<double>> table_;
};
```

The implementation file `impl.cpp`

```cpp
bool Tester::get_sum2(){
  double s = 0;
  for(auto& subtable : table_){
    for(double e : subtable){
      s += e;
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

The main file for benchmarking `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "header.h"
int main(){
  int size = 30000;
  auto tester = Tester(size);
  std::cout << "Finish constructing the tester" << std::endl; 
  {
    clock_t start = clock();
    tester.get_sum();
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << (end - start)/1000.0 << " [msec]" << std::endl; 
  }

  {
    clock_t start = clock();
    tester.get_sum2();
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << (end - start)/1000.0 << " [msec]" << std::endl; 
  }
}
```

The output of execution of `main.cpp` is

```
Finish constructing the tester
0.001 [msec]
1054.71 [msec]
```

cmake script used `CmakeLists.txt` (note that build with release mode)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_executable(main main.cpp impl.cpp)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one simply is optimized away, since you never use the result of `tester.get_sum();`. You should try with a dedicated testing framework.

Comment: @churill thanks, and true. When I added `std::cout < get_sum()`, the performance of the two became the same.

Comment: @churill My original code is much complex and returned value is actually used. But guessing from these result, is it reasonable to think that some optimization took place when implementing in the header file, but did not when splitting them?

Comment: What your code does is fairly trivial (I spotted pretty easily that it adds zero many times, and doesn't output the result), so it's likely (with header-only) that the compiler has inlined and then optimised most operations away.  With separate implementation, the compiler can't reliably make that determination, so cannot optimise that way.  For your benchmarking to be effective - you need to force the compiler to emit code to ACTUALLY DO the same set of operations REPEATEDLY.  Which, with modern (and even not so modern) compiler optimisation techniques, your code does not do.

Comment: They aren't same, you still hitting optimization, but because your `get_sum` functions are `bool` and results are predictable. Try change it to `double` and create separate objects as well as some unpredictable values. If anything, if you chagle return values to double, first function may appear much slower, but that's result of of second being optimized